# Why is C# OrderBy so fast?

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, linq, sorting

Check out this example: https://repl.it/repls/PuzzledAthleticMacroinstruction

It creates a list of objects with random values, then sorts them. You would expect the sorting to take the longest amount of time, based on big O of n*log(n). However, the sorting is much faster than generating the list.

The output is:

```
Generate list in 8421 milliseconds
Sort in 46 milliseconds
Before sorting, first element was 8445383 and last element was 11537420
After sorting, first element is 0 and last element is 11999999
```

This seems impossible.

Comment: Because it is done *lazy*. If yo do not need a single list, it does not do any sorting *at all*. If you are interested only in the first element, it will take *O(n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the code in the example does access both the first and last elements. Wouldn't the list need to be sorted for that?

Comment: You should really include the code in the question instead of just in a link

Comment: Adding to Willem Van Onsem's insightful comment, if you add `.ToList()` to the invocation, it suddenly starts taking quite some time.

Comment: @TomDane: yes, but not at the `.OrderBy(..)` itself. Only when you call `.Last()` it will indeed "order" the elements passed to it.

Comment: Which goes into what LINQ delayed execution. OrderBy is just adding a command to the execution tree because it MAY BE FOLLOWED BY MORE COMMANDS. This allows you to put commands together before executing. No execution = no time for execution. The LAST then triggers the execution.

Comment: I get `Sort in 4234 milliseconds` with `.ToList()` for listSize 1200000, and no output at all for listSize 12000000, most likely due to timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is C# OrderBy so fast?

Because it's not actually sorting the collection.  It's adding a sort operation to an expression tree and returning that expression tree for possible later evaluation.  You could then append further operations to that expression tree, and it won't be evaluated until you read the data from it.

Consider what is probably the most common use of these LINQ extension methods... querying a database.  You wouldn't want to query the database over and over for each operation added to the tree.  After all, what if one of the operations is a `.Where()` which drastically reduces the number of results.  It would be silly to materialize *all* data into memory, perform N number of operations, only to ultimately filter down the data anyway.  Instead, the tree of logical expressions is built and then converted into one large (but optimized) query against the database if and when the actual data is needed.

The same thing is happening in your code.  In fact, a careful observer would note when running your code that there is a relatively lengthy (at least human observable) amount of time between the last two statements.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Before sorting, first element was {unsorted.First().Foo} and last element was {unsorted.Last().Foo}");

Console.WriteLine($"After sorting, first element is {sorted.First().Foo} and last element is {sorted.Last().Foo}");
```

Which means the second statement it taking a noticeable amount of time to execute.  All that second statement *appears* to be doing is reading a value from a collection.  *However*, since it's the *first* operation to read from the `sorted` collection, *that* is when the expression tree is evaluated and ultimately when the collection is sorted.

If you want to force your sort operation to take place when you call `.OrderBy()`, the simplest way to materialize an entire collection in place is to append `.ToList()`:

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(element => element.Foo).ThenBy(element => element.Bar).ToList();
```

In doing so you'll find that the "sort" operation now takes a human observable amount of time, and the last two statements which output elements take no time at all.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @David. Sorry the question was removed by moderators.

Comment: @TomDane The question wasn't removed. It was marked as a duplicate. The question will remain.